# LZ78 that displays output in jTextField

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, compression

I am on a project making a GUI interface for both LZ77 and LZ78 compressors already done with the LZ77 but cant find a simple code for LZ78

I want the code to do two things shows the input in a textfield and shows the output in another textfield when the user press a button

the input will be anything example: "dabbacdabbacdabbacdabbacdeecdeecdee"

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you using for the lz77?

Comment: I am using this code http://pastebin.com/YtpiCFHD and its working no problem I need help with the LZ78